# Notifications filtering before sending it to Bluetooth BLE accessory iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

If iOS device has to pass sms and call notification to an accessory it is connected to what is the best possible way to do it?

I know that there is [Apple Notification Center Service](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/AppleNotificationCenterServiceSpecification/Introduction/Introduction.html). And once the accessory subscribe to this service of the iOS device it will get notification updates. So the accessory would get all the notifications and the service has rule sets according to which you can filter some notification on accessory side.

However, If I want filter the notifications on my device through the application and only pass relevant notifications to the accessory Is it possible or not?

Comment: Not. ANCS is the only way to receive notifications from the iOS device. The legacy HFP profile can receive incoming call details and text messages but again there is. No way to filter what is delivered.

Comment: thanks for your reply do you know, or have any tips how to use legacy HFP profile to get access to the notifications of call details and text messages.

Comment: I haven't ever looked at it, sorry.  I would presume it is in the spec at Bluetooth.com; I presume there is some sort of serial port connection that delivers notifications - See https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/profiles-overview/legacy-profiles

Comment: Actually, it is probably the Message Access Profile (MAP) - same URL as above

Comment: yes I understand that, But I don't know how to deal with any of that profile with the CoreBlueTooth framework.

Comment: You can’t. The legacy profiles are handled by iOS directly. If you have a peripheral that implements the legacy MAP profile then it can be paired through Bluetooth settings. The only way to get messages via BLE is through ANCS.